# Powershell deployment with nant - problem with script arguments

Tags: powershell, solution-deployment, cmdlets

I have a powershell script updating my solution:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
write-host $args[0]
Update-SPSolution -Identity PkbInfo.SP.wsp -literalpath $args[0] -GACDeployment
```

When I execute it with SP 2010 management shell (without Add-PSSnapin of course) it runs ok, but when I try to execute it with nant command:

```
  <target name="sp.update">
    <exec failonerror="true" program="${powershell.exe}">   
    <arg value="-noprofile" />
    <arg value="-nologo" />
    <arg value="-noninteractive" />
    <arg value="-command" />
    <arg value="${ps.script.name} ${ps.copyto.folder}" />
    </exec>
  </target>
```

I get an error:

```
     [exec] Update-SPSolution : c:\shared\PkbInfo.wsp: The specified file was no
t found.
     [exec] At C:\Users\me\Documents\production\sharepoint\nant_powershell
.ps1:5 char
     [exec] :18
     [exec] + Update-SPSolution <<<<  -Identity PkbInfo.SP.wsp -literalpath $arg
s[0] -GACDe
     [exec] ployment
     [exec]     + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (:) [Update-SPSolution], Fi
leNotFound
     [exec]    Exception
     [exec]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdl
etUpdateSo
     [exec]    lution
     [exec]
     [exec] Update-SPSolution : Zgłoszono wyjątek typu 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Pow
erShell.SPC
     [exec] mdlet+SkipCurrentRecordException'.
```

So it looks like the argument i'm passing is not parsed, which is strange, because Write-Host in both cases (with management shell and nant) displays the correct path.
Any ideas why the $args[0] in Update-SPSolution is not converted to actual argument when running with nant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and put a $() around your literal path, like so:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity PkbInfo.SP.wsp -literalpath $($args[0]) -GACDeployment
```

You can also use Resolve-Path if your path is relative

On a side note: remember that Update-SPSolution **only** works as long as you update existing artefacts (eg. no new or deleted modules/features/rootfiles)

Answer (score 0):

You try to run:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity PkbInfo.SP.wsp
```

And you get the error:

```
 [exec] Update-SPSolution : c:\shared\PkbInfo.wsp: The specified file was no  
t found.
```

Check your filename :)

(I know you can have different identity and filename, but nobody ever changes that, right?)

Comment: the 'file not found' occurs because it tries to exec `Identity PkbInfo.SP.wsp -literalpath $args[0] -GACDeployment`, so obviously i do not have a file named '$args[0]' ;)